# performSelector is calling new in if loop

Tags: ios, nstimer, performselector

i have

```
if (_moves <=19) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1.0];

}
```

And the Method:

```
- (void)changeLabelState:(NSTimer *)timer
{

[UIView transitionWithView:self.movesLeftLabel duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    self.movesLeftLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.movesLeftLabel duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        self.movesLeftLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}];
[self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}
```

So if _moves = 19, everything works fine. its changing to white and back to grey. but if the _moves = 18, it calls another time, and the transition is too fast.

how can i do it that he is not calling it another time?

Comment: Can you post more about the surround code near the `if (_moves <=19) {...}`?

Comment: theres no surround code. every move, my _moves gets --. so when the player have 19 moves left, it should start "blinking" (white-grey-white) and should not stop or get faster. i just want to start the transition at 19 moves or less.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote you code in loop, and you do not want to perform selector more than one time try to add 'break;' after perform

```
if (_moves <=19) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1.0];
     break;
}
```

or, if you want, change clause to

```
if (_moves ==19) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeLabelState:) withObject:nil afterDelay: 1.0];

}
```